# Generate several war for spring boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot

It seems that spring boot will repackage the package generated by maven package phase, and then repacke the war to make it executable.

Now I want to genrate multiple wars for different environments by a single maven command, I tried to use `maven-assembly-plugin`:

```
1 unzip the war generated by `spring-boot-maven` plugin to a directory
2 Assembly with the files in the directory, and add some other filtered resources
3 create the war
```

Check this post:[generate multiple artifacts in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490134/generate-multiple-artifacts-in-maven)

While it works, and I got multiple wars, but none of them can be executeable by `java -jar xx.war`. It seems that the classes are corrupted.

So I wonder if there is an alternative solution?

---

update my pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/as-common</source>
                                <source>src/main/as-server</source>
                                <source>src/main/as-app</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- unzip the contents of the war(executeable) generated by spring-boot to a certain directory  -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>extract_spring_war</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <echo message="extract war generated by spring-boot-maven-plugin"/>
                                        <delete dir="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}-spring" includeemptydirs="true"/>
                                        <unzip src="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.war" dest="${basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}-spring/"/>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>iterator</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <items>
                                        <item>test</item>
                                        <item>dep1</item>
                                        <item>dep2</item>
                                    </items>
                                    <pluginExecutors>
                                        <pluginExecutor>
                                            <plugin>
                                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                                                <version>2.6</version>
                                            </plugin>
                                            <goal>single</goal>
                                            <configuration>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <mainClass>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClass>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>

                                                <descriptors>
                                                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                                </descriptors>
                                            </configuration>
                                        </pluginExecutor>
                                    </pluginExecutors>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

assmbly.xml:

```
<assembly>
    <id>${item}</id>
    <formats>
        <format>war</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <!-- file from the unpacked contents -->
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/${project.build.finalName}-spring</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </fileSet>

        <!-- add environment awared resources -->
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/custom/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>${item}.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

---

Update:

At first I got the error:

```
No main class detected
```

Then I  add the following for `maven-assembly-plugin`,

```
<archive>
    <manifest>
        <mainClass>org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher</mainClass>
    </manifest>
</archive>
```

After that I repackage the wars, and I got error when I ran:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file org/springframework/boot/loader/WarLauncher
```

Comment: Can you show your pom file and the assembly descriptor how you did that?

Comment: You don't want that... You want the same artifact for different environments, the differences should be configurable. How are you going to guarantee that you have the same functionality in all wars? Are you doing all the tests on all wars (even those non-automated tests?). Generally (re)generating artifacts for different environments is something you don't want and is generally a sign that something else is wrong.

Comment: @M.Deinum: I am sure all the wars have the same functionality.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I update my pom and assembly.xml

Comment: You are but how are you proving that to your client? You cannot really guarantee that...

Comment: I am not exactly sure why this is the point? We do need to create several wars for the `almost same` application.  I just wonder if this is possible technically

Comment: What happens when you try to run one of the wars that you have repackaged? Can you share the error message that's produced?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson:I update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class files are being corrupted when you're repackaging the war file. I suspect that's because you're filtering all of the files:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>target/${project.build.finalName}-spring</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
    <filtered>true</filtered>
</fileSet>
```

You don't want to filter binary files as they may happen to contain data that looks like a `${}` placeholder. You should update the assembly to avoid applying the filtering to class files. The simplest way to do that would be to disable filtering entirely:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>target/${project.build.finalName}-spring</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
    <filtered>false</filtered>
</fileSet>
```

If you need filtering for text files, you should use two fileSets. One that includes the binary files and disables filtering, and one that includes the text files and enables filtering.

Comment: Thanks, that' the point, it works now, you save my life, I have spent almost one week for that. :)